# Excel VBA Conditional Formatting when cell is formatted as a formula Eg: ="1234"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to setup conditional formatting in VBA on a single column in a sheet. Basically I'm trying to highlight cells that are not numbers.

The tricky bit is that the cell values are defined like this in the formula bar:

```
="1234"
="4556"
="XXXX"
```

In the cell itself the values look like this:

1234

4567

XXXX

My VBA code looks like this:

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range(A1,A3)
rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1)))"
rng.FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(255,0,0)`
```

I tried the formula outside of VBA and it seems to work and evaluates to TRUE for cells that contain non-numbers and FALSE to cells that contain numbers.

Eg:

`=NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(A1)))`

However, when the VBA code is run all cells are turned red.

Comment: Your code works. I tested it and cells with values that can't be converted to numbers turn red.

Comment: Thanks :) Is there a way to dynamically set the column? Say at a later date a column gets inserted before A.

Comment: Sure. You can just build the formula string. Something like ="=NOT(ISNUMBER(VALUE(" & columnLetter & "1)))" Also I know I said your code works but it actually doesn't. The range assignment should be "Set rng = Range("A1:A3")" unless you specify A1 and A3 as variables earlier in the code.